# a ticket "to" or "for" each event. Are both correct?

Tags: prepositions, word-difference

A ticket **to** the event or **for** each event? Are they both correct and if yes, what's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

In many cases both of them are correct, however in American usage, it's more common to use "to" in order to indicate the destination in travel, whereas using "for" is more idiomatic when you buy tickets for admission.

For example:

- How much are tickets for the City Museum?
- It's $30 for my train ticket to London and $20 for my ticket for the theater.